# 'runtimeConfig' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to create a Nuxt 3 project based on installation guide: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation.
I followed it step by step. But when i want to configure `nuxt.config.ts` and i paste sample config file from https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/configuration:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    // The private keys which are only available server-side
    apiSecret: '123',
    // Keys within public are also exposed client-side
    public: {
      apiBase: '/api'
    }
  }
})
```

I'm getting a typescript error:

```
Argument of type '{ runtimeConfig: { apiSecret: string; public: { apiBase: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NuxtConfig'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'runtimeConfig' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig'.ts(2345)
```

I'm using node version 16.16.0 and Visual Studio Code is my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to update typescript version from 4.7.3 to 5.0.4 and change settings of vsc to use newer version.

Comment: I have the same problem, but my version of Nuxt it's a 5.0.4 what I need to change on VSC

Answer (score 2):

[Update Typescript IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652709/update-typescript-intellij)

the second solution to add

```
"devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "5.0.4"
    },
```

made the tric, and intellij detected automatically the good version

Answer (score 0):

Open **Volar takeover mode** will be help！

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode

The main problem is that when you open the ts file, VSCode does not use the same typescript version as volar, normally it is version 4, but you must use version 5 like volar!! You can turn on this setting to force all to use version 5

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is showing same thing in tailwind-css. this error means, nuxt don't know about tailwind so, I just run this command:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/tailwindcss
```